# Openlayers WMS layer not zooming properly with Basemap

Tags: dictionary, zooming, openlayers, geoserver, wms

I'm using a WMS layer coming from Geoserver over a OSM basemap. When I'm at a particular zoom level (1:70) then the WMS layer is on right position over Basemap, but on zooming in to see individual points the layer starts slipping off and vanishes after 2 zoom levels. By slipping off I mean it doesn't zoom in properly with basemap.

I tried to disable basemap and work only with this layer and it works fine individually, but when attached with basemap, it just slips off.

It will be a great help if anyone can point me to some resources that can solve this problem, or provide a solution to this.

Comment: Could you clarify how the layer vanishes? Does it misalign with the points? Is it completely off, or just a few meters off?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem, if the projection of both layer and basemap are different then you will always land into misaligning of points and absence of layer.
I tried to set the projection system of every element by hardcoding it, but no luck.

Solution is to set "displayProjection" (http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.displayProjection) property of map element to projection system your basemap is using.